# Wordpress theme won't switch to RTL using qTranslate plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using [qTranslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/) plugin which allows me to translate posts and fields.

The first language is English, the second language is Arabic which requires RTL design.

I followed their [FAQ](https://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/faq/) and [Wordpress' Right-to-Left Language Support](https://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support).
The FAQ of the plugin says it should work automatically but if it doesn't that I need to check Wordpress' documentation on the issue, so I did, it says this:

> Start with your main theme stylesheet (usually style.css). Save this
>   file as rtl.css Add the following attributes to the body selector:

```
direction: rtl;
unicode-bidi: embed;
```

So I created a new copy of `style.css` and named it `rtl.css` then added `direction:rtl` to the body selector.

But it's not working, when I switch the language to Arabic, it still displays LTR.

However if I add `direction:rtl` to the body selection in `style.css` it works, the theme switches to RTL.

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I managed to get this to work is by creating a new class in my css called `direction` and included it whenever the language was Arabic, by doing this

```
$currentLang = qtrans_getLanguage();
if($currentLang == 'ar') {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: In my case I found out that Wordpress didn't have any language files in wp-content/languages directory.
I've had them in another installation though. After copying them from there, things worked automatically as they should.
Check out this faq point: https://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/faq/#RTL

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to redirect browse view to read from RTL and by using qtranslate-x plugin, add code below at header.php

```
<?php
$dir_ar = 'dir="rtl"';
?>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> <?php if(qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'ar') echo $dir_ar; ?>>
```

then at function.php, use wp_enqueue_style, wp_style_add_data, to detrmine which stylesheet you need to read as rtl

```
wp_enqueue_style('theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_style_add_data('theme-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );
```

reference link:
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support
- http://princessdesign.net/wpsnippets/qtranslate/